# Time Series Regression - Non-Contiguous Dataset

Tags: regression, time-series, continuous-data

Is there a good way to run a time series regression on non-contiguous dataset, such as number of cars purchased per Quarter from a dealership (e.g. when for a reason I want to EXCLUDE certain Quarters from the dataset to determine sales baseline free of promotions)?

The model fitting (e.g. SARIMAX().fit()) must take into the consideration that x-ticks are not evenly distributed for a given dataset

The regressional model must calculate values for missing datapoints (interpolation)

There are Holt-Winters, SARIMA, etc but they are not usable for such cases.

Suggestions, modified libraries or subroutines are much appreciated

Sample dataset:

```
x = np.array([2001Q3, 2001Q4, 2002Q2, 2002Q3, 2002Q4, 2003Q3, 2004Q1, 2004Q3, 2005Q1, 2005Q3,2006Q2, 2006Q3, 2006Q4, 2007Q1, 2007Q4])
y = np.array([24, 20, 27, 29, 26, 32, 34, 30, 32, 37, 35, 39, 41, 37, 39])
```

There are some standard methods such as:

```
from scipy import optimize
from scipy import interpolate
```

One way, is to prepare an array with calculated numbers for missing datapoints (Quarters) and then apply SARIMAX.fit but I am curious if there is a more elegant way.

The resulting model must estimate all Quarters from 2001Q3 till 2007Q4, including the missing ones

Also. for sea-saw-like time series (with trend and seasonality) a linear interpolation may not work well, especially if the gap is greater than 1 missing datapoint (as in a sample dataset)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am curious if there is a more elegant way.

A more elegant way would be to keep the quarters with promotions, and add as an exogenous variable a second time series with an indicator for promotions (i.e which is 0 for quarters without promotions and 1 for quarters with promotions).

I have modeled sales data with promotions using Facebook Prophet and it has worked fairly well. (In Facebook Prophet, you don't add a second time series, just a list of promotions with their corresponding dates).

Comment: fair enough, Alex! I have not tried that. I am thinking that Prophet is not the best for a factor analysis (promotions being an event). XGBoost may be the way to go. So thought was exactly like yours: have 2 series - one without promos and one with promos. use Prophet for the one without promos to create the baseline. Then subtract calculated baseline values from the dataset with promos and use the deltas as incremental sales and run it through xgboost. The issue is indeed the lumpiness of the first dataset since for the second one it is irrelevant (factor analysis vs the time series)